# How to upload an sqlite file in an Android application from Linux home server

Tags: android, database, sqlite, data-transfer

I am planning on writing a simple Android application that is like a small directory of professors.  It will have their name, email, phone and a picture of them.  I need to manually send an sqlite file from the server to the phone.  I have been trying to research how to do this, but it looks like there are so many ways!  I'm hoping someone can point me in the best direction!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can think of, is to open an URLConnection to your server, read the response and save it to your app's database directory (or SD card).

For example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/file.sqlite");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream fos = 
    new FileOutputStream("/data/data/[your.pkg.name]/databases/file.sqlite");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;
do {
    read = bin.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    if (read > 0)
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
} while (read >= 0);
```

After that you can open your database with a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper or directly by calling SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(..):

e.g.:

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/[your.pkg.name]/databases/file.sqlite",
        null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```